# almacenar los datos de un input por medio de value en angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap

hola resulta que tengo un problema estoy haciendo una aplicación en angular con la que se clasifique por estrellas  y los valores me aparecen pero no se como puedo guardarlos.

En mi HTML tengo la siguiente sección

```
       <ngb-rating [(rate)]="starRating" [max]="5">
            <ng-template let-fill="fill" let-index="index">
              <span class="star" [class.filled]="fill === 100" [class.bad]="index < 2">&#9733;</span>
            </ng-template>

    
          </ngb-rating>
          
          <pre>rate: <b>{{starRating}}</b></pre>
```

esto me devuelve starRating el cual es el numero que aparece cuando presiono las estrellas que coloqué.

[image: imagen de estrellas con las cual pretendo calificar]

luego ese starRating para conseguir almacenarlo lo estoy pasando por un form de esta manera

```
       <form (submit)="postRatedocument()">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="documentoRate.documentRate" name="documentRate" class="form-control" value= {{starRating}} required autofocus>
            </div>
            

            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">
            <b>CALIFICAR</b>
            </button>
        </form>
```

que es lo que sucede, el input se me rellena y pretendo dejarlo como un hidden y no text pero lo que sucede es que para que el input me carge los valores tengo que escribir yo el dato ya que no me toma por defecto los valores que están en el VALUE y si no relleno yo el value no me carga en la base de datos.

mi pregunta hay alguna manera de hacer que se value se me envíe a la base de datos sin tener que modificarlo.

el input se me carga solo cuando presiono las estrellas para calificar

ejemplo: presiono la quinta estrella, el input da de valor 5.

pero al presionar el boton de CALIFICAR no se envía lo que está en el boton

si me pudieran ayudar con esto me serviría de mucho.

Comment: puedes poner la parte de componente.ts y como mandas los datos al server? Los dos snippets de codigos que has puesto en la pregunta estan en el mismo fichero?

Comment: Intenta cambiar a `[ngValue]=" starRating"`